# NSPlaceholderString initwithformat error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I receive the strangest error: whenever I press and hold a UIButton on my UIView (literally taken from the Storyboard IB and placed onto the screen with no additional edits whatsoever) I receive this error `-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]: nil argument'`

Has this happened to any of you before?

p.s. it also only happens on this particular viewcontroller...

additional note: this ONLY happens when I press and hold the button. I can't for the life of me replicate the error anyway else...

Comment: Do you have any other objects on the UIView?

Comment: Does the stacktrace from the crash help any?

Comment: It would be more easy to help if you post the code of your controller, maybe the button is triggering some method, also this is happening only in a specific controller so maybe we can found something in your code.

Comment: @rmaddy would you mind briefly explaining what the stacktrace is? Is that just the output console?

Comment: @Auser See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1